# Simple MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have the below code running and cannot find what the error is. Can anyone suggest anything I should check?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die (mysql_error());
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'table' at line 1

Comment: table is a reserved keyword in mysql

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`table` is a reserved keyword, you must escape it with backtick.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keyword List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Thank you. Obvious, but I didn't know. Cheers