# Create a stored procedure that deletes a row when entering ID for that row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a stored procedure, both in syntax and logic. I got the error below when trying it on sqlfiddle.com.

Also I'm not sure if the logic is right. Is there anyway I can check by entering the ID and the query will return a table which row that contains the ID has been deleted?

create a procedure named delete_id which deletes the row that goes by the ID

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETE_ID (ID_INPUT IN INT)
AS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM TABLE ALBUM WHERE ID=ID_INPUT;
END;
```

Expected result: Enter an Id and SQL will delete the row which contains the ID

Actual Result:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE ALBUM WHERE ID=ID_INPUT' at line 3

Comment: Remove the word `table`.  It is not part of the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple MySQL Syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415356/simple-mysql-syntax-error)

Comment: HI Gordon, even when I remove the word table. it still shows error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN INT) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM ALBUM WHERE ID=ID_INPUT' at line 1

Comment: I'm not a mysql expert but it seems you have to write the parameter list as `(IN id_input INT)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "DELIMITER //" at the start on the code and "//" at the end. So your code should look like

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `DELETE_ID`(IN `ID_INPUT` INT)   
BEGIN

DELETE FROM `ALBUM` WHERE `ID` = ID_INPUT;

END //
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how i can test the code in db-fiddle ? Like inputting an Id and see how the table altered after executing the procedure ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used db fiddle. I tested the code out two ways before posting. The first was in the mysql console and the second was in phpmyadmin.

Comment: If my code answered your problem can you mark it answered pleased